# C++ get and set values from DialogBox in Callback function

Tags: c++, callback, dialog, global-variables, outlook-addin

I have an ATL/COM Outlook-AddIn that is activated when the user tries to send a mail. If the send button is clicked a DialogBox appears. There I want to set the subject of the mail in a TextBox and rewrite this to the subject if the OK Button is clicked. This should be done in the callback function of the DialogBox. Here is what I got so far:

```
static BSTR myGlobalVar;

void __stdcall OnItemSend(IDispatch* Item, VARIANT_BOOL* Cancel)
{
    CComPtr<Outlook::_MailItem> mail;
    HRESULT hr = Item->QueryInterface(__uuidof(Outlook::_MailItem), (void**)&mail); // get the mail item

    if (hr == S_OK)
    {           
        IUnknown* mapiItem;
        if (mail->get_MAPIOBJECT(&mapiItem) == S_OK)
        {
            mail->get_Subject(&myGlobalVar); // get the current subject

            DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(L"MyDllName.dll"), (LPCWSTR)IDD_DIALOG1, 0, (DLGPROC)About); // open the DialogBox

            // here I want to set the subject with the value from the TextBox
            mail->put_Subject(&myGlobalVar);
        }
   }
}

// this is the callback function of the DialogBox
static LRESULT CALLBACK About( HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( message )
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            {
                // I want to set the value of IDC_MYTEXT to the subject, 
                // but I cannot access any global variables from here
                SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_MYTEXT, myGlobalVar);

                return TRUE;
            }

        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK) 
            {
                TCHAR szBuf[128];
                GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_MYTEXT, szBuf, 128 - 1);

                // here I want to set an global accessable variable
                myGlobalVar = (BSTR)szBuf;

                EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                return TRUE;
            }               

            break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

In the callback function I cannot access any global variables that would be available in OnItemSend as well, because I get a linker error LNK2001. What would be a good approach to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by wrapping the whole dialog handling in a class and create an instance of this class in my OnItemSend function. Then I can get and set public properties from inside my function and the static callback function as well.